# Check that Docker container has enough disk space

Tags: docker

My hard disk is getting full and I'm suspecting that my Docker container may not have enough disk space.

How can I check that the system allocated enough free disk space for Docker?

My OS is OSX.

Comment: What is the storage backend that you are using? `sudo docker info | grep Storage`

Comment: `Storage Driver: aufs`

Comment: If you haven't made any fancy modifications, then the images should be stored in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/`. Type `df -h /var/lib/docker/aufs/` and find out how much space is remaining.

Comment: If your docker container uses volumes, then it it depends on which type of volume and from where it is mounted, etc.

Comment: `find / -name aufs 2>/dev/null` doesn't return anything, so it looks like the file doesn't exist on my system.

Comment: What's the output for: `sudo ls -l /var/lib/docker`

Comment: On Docker for Mac the commands @NehalJWani is suggesting would need to be run in the VM.

Answer (score 4):

Docker for Mac's data is all stored in a VM which uses a thin provisioned qcow2 disk image. This image will grow with usage, but never automatically shrink. ([which may be fixed in 1.13](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371))

The image file is stored in your home directories `Library` area:

```
mac$ cd ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux
mac$ ls -l Docker.qcow2 
rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  46671265792 31 Jan 22:24 Docker.qcow2
```

#### Inside the VM

Attach to the VM's tty with `screen` (`brew install screen` if you don't have it)

```
$ screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
```

If you get a login prompt, user is `root` with no password. Otherwise just press enter. Then you can run the `df` commands on the Linux VM.

```
/ # df -h /var/lib/docker
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda2                59.0G     14.9G     41.1G  27% /var
```

Note that this matches the `df` output inside a container (when using `aufs` or `overlay`)

```
mac$ docker run debian df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          60G   15G   42G  27% /
tmpfs           1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda2        60G   15G   42G  27% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
```

Also note that while the VM is only using 14.9G of the 60G, the file size is 43G.

```
mac$ du -h Docker.qcow2 
43G Docker.qcow2
```

The easiest way to fix the size is to backup any volume data, "Reset" docker from the Preferences menu and start again.  [It appears 1.13 has resolved the issue and will run a compaction on shutdown.](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371)

#### `screen` notes

Exit the screen session with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd>

The Docker VM's tty get's messed up after I exit `screen` and I have to restart Docker to get a functional terminal back for a new session.

Comment: If I run `df -h` on my VM, then I get `Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none            193G  8.3G  175G   5% /`. But since there aren't 175G on my hard disk, I'm assuming this shows just virtual memory, which is irrelevant.

Comment: @octavian The qcow image is thin provisioned, so the file starts out as large as the data inside and then expands over time as you write to it. In your case it's possible the qcow file could grow to 193G if your osx file system would allow that.